# Comparing relative and absolute filepath, extracting only the relative portion

Tags: python, operating-system, filepath

I have a series of absolute folder paths that have the following pattern:

- "C:\Work\Project1\sourcedata"
- "C:\Work\Project1\scripts"
- "C:\Work\Project1\outputs\4"
- "C:\Work\Project1\outputs\3"
- "C:\Work\Project1\outputs\1"
- "C:\Work\Project1\outputs\1\hello"

I need to extract the relative paths in comparison to the folder path:
- "C:\Work\Project1"

Resulting in:

- "sourcedata"
- "scripts"
- "outputs\4"
- "outputs\3"
- "outputs\1"
- "outputs\1\hello"

Is there a method of doing this using os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to manipulate paths, starting with Python 3.4:

```
from pathlib import WindowsPath

WindowsPath(r"C:\Work\Project1\sourcedata").relative_to(r"C:\Work\Project1")
# WindowsPath('sourcedata')

WindowsPath(r"C:\Work\Project1\outputs\1\hello").relative_to(r"C:\Work\Project1")
# WindowsPath('outputs/1/hello')
```

Comment: Can you change the answer to not apply only to Windows? (upvoted as this seems like the correct answer)

Comment: os.path.relpath was the best solution